# NodeJS: Download file from users Google Drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

**Hi,**

this might be more theoretical than practical but Im lost and I cant imagine Im the only one.

What I try to achieve is downloading a file (XLXS in this case) from Google Drive of a User from now on until end of time every day without re-authentification.

**What I did in points:**

- wrote the code following a tutorial (the code itslef should not be needed now)
- as the user I created a new project on the Google Cloud Platform
- as the user I asked for Drive API key
- I got two accesses accesses a service account and OAuth Client and am using the OAuth

One of the parts of the software is a JSON file with credentials ***(credentials.json)*** which I have filled in.

**When I run it the first time Google API tells me in the console this:**

```
Authorize this app by visiting this url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/ ...
```

and

```
Enter the code from that page here:
```

Than when I open the URL in a browser whenre my user is logged in I have to ogrant access to the project app by the user and when that is done I get a key. When I enter the key to the terminal a new json file is generated - ***token.js*** and voila everything works.

**File is downloaded and all is done.**

**But this is where the fun begins:**
After few days my token expires and I get an error:

```
error: 'invalid_grant',
error_description: 'Token has been expired or revoked.'
```

So I have to delete the token.json, and create a new one by following the steps mentioned above. (URL, authorize, copy paste key, token generated).

**But and thats the issue** - I have to do this manually becasue of the permissions that I have to give and becasue of the key I have to copy into the console.

**And this is the problem** - I cant figure out a way on how to solve this. I have read half of the internet about this issue but the best I have found was taht its because the "Project App" that is given permissions to is not realeased, its in testing phase and thats why the permissions only last few days. Doh. I tried pushing the app into production but it wanted from me a huge LIST of items that need to be done before I can do so ... and I still feel thats kinda a overkill.. I dont want the app to be public or what not ...

Am I missing something? Isnt there a simple way on how to access own files from Google Drive via NODE.JS and save them? Simple as in API key - done, from now on until end of time?

**Thank you**

**Oliver**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the authentication flow for server-side Apps. And you should use the returned `refresh token` to obtain a new `access token` as access tokens expire.

See [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline).

---

### From the above docs:

> To refresh an access token, your application sends an HTTPS POST request to Google's authorization server (https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token) that includes the following parameters:

```js
client_id -> The client ID obtained from the API Console.
client_secret -> The client secret obtained from the API Console.
grant_type -> As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field's value must be set to refresh_token.
refresh_token -> The refresh token returned from the authorization code exchange.
```

Take special note of the "grant_type" as it must be set to "refresh_token".